# Simplify the huge determinant product

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation, memory, arithmetic

I try to get the following determinant product result,

```
 nn = 5;
 Unprotect[Times];
 s1[k1_, x1_] s2[k2_, x1_] := 
 If[k1 == k2 || Abs[k1 - k2] == 4, g[k1, k2, x1], 0];
 res = 
  Det[Table[s1[i1, i2], {i1, 1, nn}, {i2, 1, nn}]]*
   Det[Table[s2[i1, i2], {i1, 1, nn}, {i2, 1, nn}]] // ExpandAll;
 res
```

If $nn\leq 6$, it is easy to get the result. Now, I want to know, is it possible to find a way to 
increase nn to $12$ or larger ? The final expression should be `ExpandAll`.

**Update:**

Now I realized that $nn=12$ is really too large. It is very difficult if we cannot use some effective arithmetic. So, is it possible for $nn=8$ ?

Comment: Can you explain what you think you are doing when you `Unprotect[Times];`?

Comment: @bill s  just to define the  product s1[k1_, x1_] s2[k2_, x1_] . Times is  Protected. Of course, this is not a safe method.

Comment: You can use `TagSetDelayed` instead and that is vastly preferable to changing `Times`. `s1 /: s1[k1_, x1_] s2[k2_, x1_] := 
  If[k1 == k2 || Abs[k1 - k2] == 4, g[k1, k2, x1], 0];`

Comment: Also, to handle dimension of 12 you will need to figure out a way that avoids the intermediate determinant computations. The intermediate swell from those will be quite large (that might be an understatement).

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau  Yes, nn=12 is really too difficult.  Can I ask you to have a try for nn=8 for this problem ?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau might be an understatement?!? I've crushed computers trying to calculate a determinate that large.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this is just some random thoughts and observations. I will try to morph it into a coherent answer, soon.

First, a determinant can be reasonably calculated using `LUDecomposition`, e.g.

```
Clear[ludet];
ludet[nn_] := ludet[nn] = 
 Block[{u, s1},
  u = First@LUDecomposition@Table[s1[i1, i2], {i1, 1, nn}, {i2, 1, nn}];
  Times @@ Diagonal[u SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j >= i -> 1, Dimensions@u]]
 ]
```

On my computer, `nn == 11` took 40 s, so `nn == 12` might be in reach.

Examining the results from the lower orders, you quickly note that the determinant is recursive, e.g.

```
ludet[n] = ludet[n - 1] nterm
```

So, you can build up to `n == 8` or `n == 12` by examining the determinants for the lower `n` values.  My thought is to convert those lower order terms into patterns for use on the higher order terms, i.e. pre-generating the conversion rules to speed things along. This is roughly

```
origconversion = s1[k1_, x1_] s2[k2_, x1_] :> If[
   k1 == k2 || Abs[k1 - k2] == 4, g[k1, k2, x1], 0];
newconversions = {};

Block[{term = #, eterm, res},
  eterm = # (# /. s1 -> s2)& @ term;
  res = eterm /. newconversions;
  If[ !FreeQ[res, s1|s2],
    res = res /. origconversion;
    newconversions = {makePattern[eterm, res]}~Join~newconversions
  ];
  res
]& /@ ludet[n] (* run for each n *)
```

with `makePattern` the missing piece.

Comment: Seems promising! Thanks for your try for this problem.  Looking forward to your final answer.

Comment: @Orders it will be at least another day until I can get back to this.